# how to upload the image in worklight

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

How can I upload an image to a SQL database?

Current mysql query:

```
CREATE TABLE upload (
id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
type VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
size INT NOT NULL,
content MEDIUMBLOB NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
```

html file

```
<form method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="2000000">
   <input type="file" id="userfile"  name="userfiles">  <br>
   <input type="submit"  id="upload" value="Uploadimage "name="uploads"onclick="upload()">      
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about that SQL query, it doesn't tell much.

What you need to do is [base64 encode the image](https://www.google.co.il/search?q=base64%20encode&oq=base64%20encode&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.4151j0j1&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=91&ie=UTF-8) and save this string to your database.
Similarly when you want to pull the image and display it, you will need to decode the string back to an image.